# How do you integrate a filename reference into a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filenames

I'm using HLOOKUP() and need to reference a filename within the HLOOKUP().  Because the filenames change from `daily(3)` to `daily(4)` ... `daily(200)`, I'm using CONCATENATE() to change the filename to 3, 4, ... 200.

```
=HLOOKUP(E$1,'daily(3).csv'!$1:$2,2,FALSE)

=CONCATENATE("'daily(",A428,").csv'!$1:$2")
```

'daily(3).csv'!$1:$2

How can I integrate the cell reference within the HLOOKUP()?

Comment: You'll need to put the file path in brackets `[FilePath]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Indirect option.
So it would become `=HLOOKUP(E$1,INDIRECT(CELL),2,FALSE)` where CELL is a reference to the cell that your `CONCATENATE` function is in.

Also see: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/684642-use-text-cell-part-reference-formula.html

And: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261

Putting it all together in a single formula:

```
=HLOOKUP(E$1,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'daily(",A428,").csv'!$1:$2")),2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Not really sure how either answer should be a -1... Upvoted so at least the accepted answer is not negative.

Comment: @pnuts, added an edit to try to flesh out the answer. I agree this is really not adding much